# Power sets intersection confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In one of the answers to this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3479243/edit

I do not understand why:

$\begin{aligned}
    x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X}) &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \dots \cap X_{n-1} \cap X_n) \\
    &\iff x \subseteq (X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \dots \cap X_{n-1} \cap X_n) 
    \end{aligned}$

Can anyone help me explain why this part holds true, how can $x$ being an element of the power set of intersection of sets imply it is a subset of the intersection of sets?? This might be obvious but I cannot seem to understand this part. I woula appreciate the explanation.

Comment: By def, $x \in \mathcal P (A) \text {  iff  } x \subseteq A$ because the Power-set of a set $A$ is the set having as elements the *subsets* of $A$

Comment: Quite.  While $X_1\cap X_2\cap \dots \cap X_n$ may look like a scary beast with a lot of symbols and characters used to represent it... it is still just a set.  A set with many symbols and implications, yes, but just a set like any other set.  If we were to replace the big scary block of symbols there in the expression by letting $A=X_1\cap X_2\cap \dots \cap X_n$, you see that the implication there is simply the $x\in \mathcal{P}(A)\iff x\subseteq A$ property.